# Data Set Configuration Error in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

A [Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370353) data set is connected to Google Data Studio then explored in chart using data range.
For 1 or 2 days, data is visible in chart and we can also set range that period of time but after 2 days it shows the screen:

[image: error_screenshot]

The data set is connected for some time or some days after this error occurs:

> **Data Set Configuration Error**
> Data Studio cannot connect to your data set. Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set.

Comment: If the answers below do not resolve the issue, have a look through the steps in the Google Data Studio support article - [Troubleshooting guide: Resolve issues with charts, reports, and data sources](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/12182485)

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue, because I changed the owner of data source. I fixed it by changing the "data credentials".

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was my issue, I changed and fixed!!

Answer (score 4):

This issue seems to be normally related to updates in underlying Spreadsheets data, for example, adding new columns. If that's the case, you can [refresh the data source fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7083608) to get access to the data again. Also, check for changes in the file that might break the connection, like change of ownership.

In case this does not apply to your case, my suggestion is to go to the [Data Studio Community site](https://support.google.com/datastudio/community?hl=en) where you can check similar questions and even get responses by Data Studio team.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue may stem from the original source being a sheets file. I recently came across an issue where pointing to a view that is made off of a sheet tab was having this same exact problem.

We tried changing credentials, refreshing, etc and nothing worked. Turned out, you need to navigate to "Manage Data Sources" --> "Add Dataset" --> and select Google Sheets. You should be prompted to approve connection to Google Drive. Do this. Even if you are not literally pulling a sheet, do this. To be clear our workflow is as follows: team inputs information in sheets --> sheet is loaded in BQ --> create a view off of the table in BQ that is the sheet so we can manipulate as such --> point the dashboard to the view in BQ.

Upon doing so, refresh the connection and you should see data populate the table/chart.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the data source owner.
by changing the owner it works for me , because had a permission issue with the owner

1. Click on Data Credentials on the top menu.
2. Update Credentials Owner

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today(https://twitter.com/wey_gu/status/1385101021576372228), for the BigQuery data source being imported in data studio, for the reason the same data source can be imported properly by my project owner role account, it's suspected as permission caused issue.

By checking all predefined IAM roles related to BigQuery, it's found that the `BigQuery Job User` role is needed as the import action is underlying yet another BigQuery Job being triggerred.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Connection option in your Data Source. From here select the appropriate data sheet and click on RECONNECT OPTION. This is prompt if any issues identified in your excel and it will automatically fix the issue. Now you data set configuration error will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I have a single Google Sheet that I personally own that was getting this message.

I had no Reconnect prompt or owner credential problems listed because I was the owner.

I needed to reauthorize Data Studio / Looker Studio to access my Google Drive.

1. Click on the data visualization element to select
2. Click the pencil icon under the data visualiation element's "data source" list
3. Click "<- Edit Connection" along the left
4. Click the button to authorize Looker Studio to access your Google Drive (user account selection pop-up will show)
5. Refresh the page or screen

Repeat as necessary for each data set and visualization element until all data sets are reconnected.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred if you changed the data source or reconnect same data source to see updated fields. If you are facing this issue for any component then selected that component and go to "Setup", Once you reached there you will find option in first row "Data Source" for that component" Just click on pencil icon and select the right data source even if the same file, then select again as there might be additional fields added or modify in the original data source. Once you reconnect the component will populate the data from the data source. I hope this helps.